# how to use axios (post) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, postman, axios

In react application i want to submit input field value to database using axios/post method,since i am new to react i don't have any clear idea.
can anyone help me with examples? Thanks in advance

i tried following  program

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

var panelStyle = {
    'max-width': '80%',
    margin: '0 auto'
}

class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();

    this.state = {
      formFields: {username: ''}
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style={panelStyle}>
      <div class="panel panel-heading">React Forum - Register</div>
      <div class="panel panel-body">
        <form onsubmit={this.formHandler(this.state.formFields)}>
          <strong>Username:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nathaniel" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.username} /> <br />
          <strong>Email:</strong> <br /> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="me@example.com" /> <br />
          <strong>Confirm Email:</strong> <br /> <input type="email" name="confirmemail" placeholder="me@example.com" /> <br />
          <strong>Password:</strong> <br /> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" /> <br />
          <strong>Confirm Password:</strong> <br /> <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="********" /> <br /><br />
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Register Account</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    );
  }

  inputChangeHandler(e) {
   let formFields = {...this.state.formFields};
   formFields[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
   this.setState({
    formFields
   });
  }

  formHandler(formFields) {
   axios.post('/api/register', formFields)
     .then(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       //Perform action based on response
   })
     .catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
       //Perform action based on error
     });
  }
}

export default Register
```

and got following error in console

```
index.js:2178 Warning: The tag <children> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

Comment: That's just a warning from React.

Comment: still i am not getting output

Comment: There's a lot of mistakes in your code. Try read thru the [docs](https://reactjs.org/) and maybe do a couple of tutorials before jump right into creating apps.

Comment: For Axios post, you can read the [example](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) section on its README.md. You can do your Ajax post in `formHandler()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxWidth` instead `max-width`.
Use `onSubmit={(e) => this.formHandler(e, this.state.formFields)}` instead `this.formHandler(this.state.formFields)` because we need variable `e` to prevent form request html

Use

```
formHandler(e, formFields) {
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

instead `inputChangeHandler(e) {}`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

var panelStyle = {
    maxWidth: '80%',
    margin: '0 auto'
}
```

Here the code can run.

```
class Register extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            formFields: {username: ''}
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="panel panel-primary" style={panelStyle}>
                    <div className="panel panel-heading">React Forum - Register</div>
                    <div className="panel panel-body">
                        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.formHandler(e, this.state.formFields)}>
                            <strong>Username:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nathaniel" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.username} /> <br />
                            <strong>Email:</strong> <br /> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="me@example.com" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.email}/> <br />
                            <strong>Confirm Email:</strong> <br /> <input type="email" name="confirmemail" placeholder="me@example.com" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.confirmemail}/> <br />
                            <strong>Password:</strong> <br /> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.password}/> <br />
                            <strong>Confirm Password:</strong> <br /> <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="********" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.confirmpassword}/> <br /><br />
                            <button className="btn btn-primary">Register Account</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }

    inputChangeHandler(e) {
        let formFields = {...this.state.formFields};
        formFields[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            formFields
        });
    }

    formHandler(e, formFields) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api/register', formFields)
            .then(function(response){


                console.log(response);
                //Perform action based on response
            })
            .catch(function(error){


                console.log(error);
                //Perform action based on error
            });
    }
}

export default Register
```

Comment: You are not answering the question, which is (as I understand) how to use Axios in React.

Comment: It is not a good idea to pass `() => {}` as property since it will trigger unwanted renderings, better to use a named function.

Comment: Your way is fine. But usually I will use [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to send request. May be you can use [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/) to support submit form easier.

Comment: But what do you use to send requests under Redux? Like `fetch`? Since Redux doesn't provide a way to do HTTP requests out of the box.

Comment: Adding to @ThanhNgo - use redux-thunk ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set it up using with create-react-app. I am a fan of using `async/await`. The `handleSubmit` and `handleChange` functions will automatically get called with the event and it is easy to reference state from inside `handleSubmit` to get the data you want to send in the post request. Sometimes, there is no choice but to use a callback style function in the JSX - like `(e) => this.whatever(e, this.state.whatever)`, but if it is avoidable I like to avoid it.  Unrelated, but you can pull username, email, etc off of the `formFields` state in render to save having to type out this.state a lot.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import axios from 'axios'

    class Register extends Component {

      state = {
        formFields: { user: '', email: '' }
      }  

      handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { formFields } = this.state
        try {
          let response = await axios.post('/api/register', formFields)
          // handle response
        } catch (error) {
          // handle error
        }

      }

      handleChange = e => {
        const { formFields } = this.state
        formFields[e.target.name] = e.target.value
        this.setState({ formFields })
      }

      render() {
        const { username, email } = this.state.formFields
        return () {
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               <strong>Username:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nathaniel" onChange={this.handleChange} value={username} /> <br />
               <strong>Email:</strong> <br /> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="me@example.com" onChange={this.handleChange} value={email}/> <br />
            <button>Register Account</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        }
      }
    }

export default Register
```